# Android shared preferences retrieve username and password

Tags: android, authentication, sharedpreferences

Im having trouble with retrieving username and password from android's sharedpreferences. I use this code to save the username and pass

```
SharedPreferences prefs=getSharedPreferences("File", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor e=  prefs.edit();
       e.putString("Email", "example@example.com").putString("Password", "password1");
       e.commit();
       e.putString("Email", "example_2@example.com").putString("Password", "password2");
       e.commit();
       String s=prefs.getString("Email","not found");
```

But i dont know how to retrieve information for user to log in. Can anybody help me figure out

Comment: Simple concepts of Java Hashmap, look it up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Create Share Preference:**

```
SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("Login", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor Ed=sp.edit();
Ed.putString("Unm",Value );              
Ed.putString("Psw",Value);   
Ed.commit();
```

**Get Value from Share preference:**

```
SharedPreferences sp1=this.getSharedPreferences("Login",null);

String unm=sp1.getString("Unm", null);       
String pass = sp1.getString("Psw", null);
```

Comment: yes yes, i just had id figured out. Thank alot :) this is the solution i was looking for!

Comment: ok that Good dear, if this is useful to you then accept answer..so it will help to other also..

Comment: I have a driver app and a rider app in the same package.  I am trying to get the current rider id from the driver app.  I did as you did above but riderId is being returned as null?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: App A:
// .. create a shared preference - share current userid with Driver
String currentRider = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("Current_User", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sp.edit();
        ed.putString("rider", currentRider );
        ed.commit();
App B:
 // .... Get Value from Share preference (RiderActivity).....
        SharedPreferences sp1 = this.getSharedPreferences("Current_User", 0);
        riderId = sp1.getString("rider", null);
        Log.d("RIDERID", "RiderId = " +riderId);

Answer (score 0):

You need to give different keys for different values, otherwise the second email will erase the first one. See shared preferences as a persistent hashmap :

```
   //keep constants, don't use their values. A constant has more meaning
   SharedPreferences prefs=getSharedPreferences("File", MODE_PRIVATE );
   SharedPreferences.Editor e=  prefs.edit();
   //keys should be constants as well, or derived from a constant prefix in a loop.
   e.putString("Email1", "example@example.com").putString("Password1", "password1");
   e.putString("Email2", "example_2@example.com").putString("Password2", "password2");
   //commit once, not twice
   e.commit();

   //not found should be a constant in a xml resource file
   String mail1=prefs.getString("Email1","not found");
   String mail2=prefs.getString("Email2","not found");
```