# Shared Preference value not getting printed in Android

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I want to save server IP and path in my android form in Shared preference and later on want to retrieve those values by another java prog. to connect to server and download files. etc.

So, first i tried to print the sharedpreference values in **New.java**, where the values are stored in **Setting.java**, the 1st java file is calling the second and **"Welcome"** is getting printed, but the saved values in shared preferences in not getting printed.

Following are my files:

**Setting.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Setting extends Activity {

    protected static final Toast NULL = null;
    Button btn1;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.setting_page);


        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        final EditText  ip  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ip);
        final EditText  path  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.path);





        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("IP_PATH",0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("flag",true);
                editor.putString("IP",ip.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("PATH",path.getText().toString());
                editor.commit();






                Intent i = new Intent(Setting.this,New.class);
                //intent.putExtra("username",getIntent().getExtras().getString("username").toString());
                startActivity(i);

            }

        });

    }

}
```

**New.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class New extends Activity {


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.data);
       //System.out.println("Welcome to the home page !!");

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        tv.setText("Welcome");

        SharedPreferences prfs = getSharedPreferences("IP_PATH", 0);
        String s = prfs.getString("IP", "");

        Toast.makeText(New.this, s , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
```

**Errors:**

```
06-16 00:06:25.900: I/Adreno200-EGL(23644): Local Patches: NONE
06-16 00:06:25.900: I/Adreno200-EGL(23644): Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
06-16 00:06:37.740: D/-heap(23644): GC_CONCURRENT freed 152K, 4% free 8035K/8327K, paused 13ms+2ms, total 49ms
06-16 00:17:27.690: E/Trace(24124): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-16 00:17:28.030: I/Adreno200-EGL(24124): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:299>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_RB1.04.01.01.06.043_msm7627a_JB_REL_RB1.2_Merge_release_AU (Merge)
06-16 00:17:28.030: I/Adreno200-EGL(24124): Build Date: 01/29/13 Tue
06-16 00:17:28.030: I/Adreno200-EGL(24124): Local Branch: 
06-16 00:17:28.030: I/Adreno200-EGL(24124): Remote Branch: m/jb_rel_rb1.2
06-16 00:17:28.030: I/Adreno200-EGL(24124): Local Patches: NONE
06-16 00:17:28.030: I/Adreno200-EGL(24124): Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
06-16 00:17:36.120: D/-heap(24124): GC_CONCURRENT freed 174K, 5% free 7985K/8327K, paused 17ms+2ms, total 40ms
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782994/android-shared-preferences-retrieve-username-and-password)

Comment: Why're you using SharedPreferences instead of pass ip value via Intent to Settings activity?

Comment: There are so many java file where I need the IP and Path values, and my app need the used to set the IP and Path value only one ...

Comment: Do you get any error ? The app crashed ?

Comment: Toast is empty or showing wrong value?

Comment: no toast appearing al all

Comment: @pali what about other vars? Have you tried to output them?

Comment: ya ya I have tried initially for bot and later on I tried to get it done with at least any one variable .

Comment: Before retrieving it, first check if the IP and PATH were written successfully into the SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` as second parameter while getting shared preferences.

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("IP_PATH",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

Comment: This is not making any change

Comment: Have you done this at both places i.e. while saving value in shared preferences as well as getting it in another file?

Comment: Its working fine at my end, if you need the sample project, i can email u

Comment: My original program is working for me if I am using a textview to print, but not in toast, so problem solved anyways ... thanks for your cooperation